# Using ordered field axioms if 1 $\leq x$, then $x \leq x^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, real-numbers

I am working with ordered field axioms where the operations are addition and multiplication.
Here's what I have thus far:

I have 1 $\leq x$ and if I just multiply by $x$ on both sides I should have $x \leq x^{2}$ but can I just assume that $x^2$ is more than $x$? Are there any other axioms that I should be using or are there other steps I must prove?

Answer (score 3):

You're using the transitive property with the multiplicative property. You know that $0\leq 1$ and $1\leq x$. Hence, $0\leq x$ by transitivity.

The multiplicative property, which you may need to prove, says that for $0\leq a$ and $c\leq b$, we have that $a\cdot c\leq a\cdot b$. So we have, since $0\leq x$:
$$1\cdot x \leq x\cdot x $$
Hence, $x\leq x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach. Given: $x \geq 1.$

Therefore, $x^2 - 2x + 1 = (x - 1)^2 \geq 0.$

Therefore, $x^2 \geq 2x - 1 \geq 2x - x$ [since $x \geq 1$] $~= x.$